# Работа с файлами сайта html+php+js

Tags: javascript, php, html

имеется сайт, который состоит из большого количества файлов, преимущественно php. Возможно ли как-то отследить путь передачи данных от самого начала до самого конца. Например, начальный_файл->второй_файл->......->конечный_файл

Comment: Передачи каких данных куда ?

Comment: Конечно можно отследить. Смотрите по коду что куда идёт

Comment: Функция `debug_backtrace`.